# How to write multiple replace in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a python dictionary of key, value pairs and I want to replace some words in a string which are the keys in the dictionary with their corresponding values.

I have tried some code which are found online.Here is the example:

```py
    test_dict = {'a/a': 'result1', "a/a b/b c/c": "result2"}

    sentence = "<<a/a>> something <<a/a b/b c/c>> something"

    result = multiple_replace(test_dict, sentence)

    def multiple_replace(dict, text):
        regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))
        return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text)
```

I expected the result to be `<<result1>> something <<result2>> something`

The actual output is `<<result1>> something <<result1 b/b c/c>> something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your first relpaced key `'a/a'` is part of another key `'a/a b/b c/c'`. The longer key does not replace anymore because the rule for `'a/a'` changes the text so it wont find `'a/a b/b c/c'` anymore.

You can avoid this if you sort the keys by decreasing length, so longer ones are replaced first:

```
import re

def multiple_replace(d, text):
    # sort keys by -len so longer ones come first (you could use reverse=True as well)
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, 
                                             sorted(d.keys(),key=lambda x:-len(x)))))
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: d[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text)

test_dict = {'a/a': 'result1', "a/a b/b c/c": "result2"}

sentence = "<<a/a>> something <<a/a b/b c/c>> something"

result = multiple_replace(test_dict, sentence)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
<<result1>> something <<result2>> something
```

You will still have problems if the *value* that was replaced contains part of a shorter key, it will be partially replaced again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code replaced all of the `a/a`'s it found in the string, meaning that there was no longer a `a/a b/b c/c` to be replaced.

If you surrounded each key w/ `<<` and `>>`, searched for *that*, and replaced it putting back the `<<` & `>>`, you would avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<<a/a b/b c/c>>` will be replaced by `'a/a': 'result1'` resulting in `"<<result1 b/b c/c>>"` before the `a/a b/b c/c` replacement would happen.

You should do the replace starting with the more specific to the less specific. One way to accomplish this is to use `OrderedDict` and define your rules in the other direction:

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

test_dict = OrderedDict([("a/a b/b c/c", "result2"), ('a/a', 'result1'),])

sentence = "<<a/a>> something <<a/a b/b c/c>> something"

def multiple_replace(dict, text):
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text)

result = multiple_replace(test_dict, sentence)
```

The output is: `<<result1>> something <<result2>> something`